# Legrand Orange Book and Polyglossia. Any Idea how to combine?

Tags: polyglossia

I've tried to combine Legrand Orange Book with `polyglossia` (greek) without any success so far. To be honest, checking the internals `-structure.tex-` I realized that would be a difficult task to my (La)TeX skills. Any idea how to decouple the font(s) settings from the book design and to use `polyglossia` for other languages?

Comment: Καλημέρα and [welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.